# How to start Yi-editor after I cabal install it?

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-platform

I followed HaskellWiki, but I've still have no idea that how to start it.
I've tried:

```
yi
ghci yi
import Yi
main
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might need to add `$HOME/.cabal/bin` to your `PATH` variable:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.cabal/bin:$PATH"
```

If `yi` still fails after that (or with an explicit invocation like `~/.cabal/bin/yi`), then it either failed to install, or should at least print out a relevant error message which could help further.

Note that, to my understanding, Yi's development since 2009 or so has been sporadic; you might want to consider Emacs with [haskell-mode](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Haskell_mode_for_Emacs) or another editor if you're not just trying Yi out of curiosity.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using MacOS and when I install yi using terminal command I get the following feedback:

> Installing library in
>
> /Users/calvin/Library/Haskell/ghc-7.6.3/lib/yi-0.7.0/lib Installing
>
> executable(s) in
>
> /Users/calvin/Library/Haskell/ghc-7.6.3/lib/yi-0.7.0/bin Registering
>
> yi-0.7.0... Installed yi-0.7.0

So I could run it in `Users/calvin/Library/Haskell/ghc-7.6.3/lib/yi-0.7.0/bin`.